# Which dimension is needed to represent a Lie algebra as a matrix algebra (as in Ado's Thm)?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose $\mathfrak g$ is a real finite dimensional Lie algebra. If I understand it correctly, Ado's Theorem states that there is a real vector space $V$ and an injective Lie algebra homomorphism $\pi:\mathfrak g \to \mathrm{End}(V)$.

My question is what the smallest dimension of the vector space $V$ is that is needed. I believe that if $\mathfrak g$ has only a trivial center, that then the answer is $\mathrm{dim}(\mathfrak g)$, because one can use the adjoint representation. But is this really the minimal one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this need not be the minimal one.
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be an $n$-dimensional Lie algebra over a field $K$ of characteristic zero. Define an invariant of $\mathfrak{g}$ by
$$\mu (\mathfrak{g}):=\min \{\dim_K (M) \mid M \text{ is a faithful $\mathfrak{g}$-module}\}.$$
For complex simple Lie algebras $\mathfrak{s}$, for example, we always have $\mu (\mathfrak{s})< \dim (\mathfrak{s})$, except for type $E_8$. Here is a small table over $\Bbb C$.

\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\mathfrak{g} & \dim (\mathfrak{g}) & \mu(\mathfrak{g}) \\
\hline
A_n, \; n\ge 1 & (n+1)^2-1 & n+1 \\
B_2 & 10 & 4 \\
B_n, \; n\ge 3 & 2n^2+n & 2n+1 \\
C_n, \; n\ge 3 & 2n^2+n & 2n \\
D_n, \; n\ge 4 & 2n^2-n & 2n \\
E_6 & 78 & 27 \\
E_7 & 133 & 56 \\
E_8 & 248 & 248 \\
F_4 & 52 & 26 \\
G_2 & 14 & 7 \\
\end{array}

In general, the question about the minimal dimension is quite difficult and we only have lower and upper bounds. For references see the papers (my papers and other papers) in [this article](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_24_pre_lie.pdf).

For example, let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a *nilpotent* Lie algebra of dimension $n$ and nilpotency class
$k$. Denote by $p(j)$ the number of partitions of $j$ and let
$$p(n,k)=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{n-j}{k-j}p(j).$$
Then $\mu(\mathfrak{g})\le p(n,k)$. If $k=n-1$, with $n\ge 3$, then $n\le \mu(\mathfrak{g})$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I am a little bit confused by the definition of $\mu(\mathfrak g)$, are (faithful) $\mathfrak g$-modules the same thing as (faithful) linear representations? If yes, how are the dimensions related? Sorry, I am not so familiar with abstract algebra.

Comment: Yes, faithful module means injective linear representation. So exactly what you have asked.

Comment: Totally off-topic here, but another reminder that $B_2$ "should" be called $C_2$ , as proposed in https://mathoverflow.net/q/52323/27465.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm mainly interested in real Lie algebras (in particular, subalgebras of $\mathfrak{su}(N)$). I surely can complexify my (real) Lie algebra and then apply the result in your paper (if that algebra is reductive) but that's in general not optimal right?

Comment: Most of the results in the literature are also valid for real Lie algebras, or can be easily adapted, so there is no problem.